# .crt to .p12 file conversion gives "unable to load certificates" error

Tags: resttemplate, mutual-authentication

I have a name.crt file i convert it using the following command
openssl pkcs12 -export -in name.crt -inkey name.key -out name.p12 -name "name".
I get the following error 
unable to load certificates
but the name.p12 file gets generated which I am not able to use as it shows EOF when using with rest template.
I tried the process by removing ^M from name.crt file which again shows
unable to load certificates